# Как отделить нужную часть?

Tags: python

есть такой output:

```
                    Starting at:
         $0.06 USD # нужное
         $0.05 USD
```

Я полагаю,что можно отделить с помощью регулярных выражений, но большое кол-во пробелов меня немного смущает, помогите.

Comment: `\$\d+\.\d{2} USD` - так вроде

Comment: Сделайте ответ пожалуйста, не понял

Comment: поясните, вы хотите конкретно `$0.06 USD` выбрать или все значения сразу?

Comment: Только 0.06 без $ и USD

Comment: только одно из двух?

Comment: Да, только одну

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правы, вам подойдут регулярные выражения. Самый очевидный способ сделать это - через группировку нужной части в круглые скобки. Пример:

```
import re
s="\n   $0.06 USD   \n" #ваша строка
r =re.search('\$(\d+\.\d{2}) USD', s)
print (r.group(1)) #0.06
```

Поиск будет осуществляться по шаблону `\d+\.\d{2}`. Метод search вернёт первое совпадение в виде объекта Match, а остальные отсечёт.

Объект Match в свою очередь будет содержать найденные значения в группах. Первая группа (с индексом 0) - это выражение целиком, вторая (с индексом 1) - первое соответствие шаблону в первых скобках (у нас они одни, так что на этом поиск закончится)